# How to connect docker containers in separate deployments on the same host machine using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having hard time figuring out how to interconnect containers which belong to different docker-compose projects running on the same host.

Let's say, I'm having a set of containers in **Deployment A**:

```
root@debussy:~# docker ps | awk '{print $2}' | grep "cl"
cl-worker:latest
cl-nginx:latest
cl-app:latest
cl-rabbitmq:latest
cl-memcached:latest
cl-db:latest
```

All these containers where launched from a separate configuration file `deployment-a.yml`. Now, we also have a different **Deployment B**, with its own `deployment-b.yml:

```
root@debussy:~# docker ps | awk '{print $2}' | grep "stockagents"
stockagents-app:latest
```

Is it possible to access Database(`cl-db` container) from `stockagents-app` by some specific configuration in `deployment-b.yml` and/or `deployment-a.yml` ?

**NOTE:** I know how to do it using pure `docker` command and linking containers via `--link`, but is there a method to achieve the same behaviour using only  `docker-compose` and its configuration files ?

Comment: you can use skydns and regulator to do automatic dns registration when a docker container is created.  it is pretty cool. then your containers can refer to each other by name.

Comment: @Greg fast googling shows that skydns requires `etcd` to run, which in turn requires it's own configuration. Moreover, I'm running on ubuntu, which does not have etcd enabled by default :(   This seems as a sophisticated solution for general cases of inter-host communication between containers.

Comment: it is a sophisticated problem, though, right? you have independent compositions which you want to 'discover' each other.  is there only one docker instance, or is there potentially many (swarm,fleet,k8s,etc)? it sounds like you want something lightweight. if this is a single docker, perhaps what you want is a volume that each composition can mount to communicate with? you know, perhaps a directory that one writes 'i am at X address' and the other reads that?

Comment: @Greg well, my current deployment is on single machine only. Right now, the possibility of running it on multiple hosts is not considered. Directory sharing is an interesting idea, thanks for bringing it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that recent versions of `docker-compose` (1.5.2 at least) have support for ["external_links" option](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/yml/#external-links) in `docker-compose.yml` file which allows to specify containers started outside of the current configuration.

This is exactly the feature I was looking for when trying to share common services (MySQL for example) between containers in separate deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your demands are outgrowing the opportunities of docker-compose. You need to mess with orchestration tool (more or less complex). We use Ubuntu too and for our environment `SkyDNS` + `SkyDock` seem to be a good and simple solution (of course no `etcd` needed). Deployment includes three steps: you just need to pull images, reconfigure docker daemon and launch `SkyDNS` and `SkyDock`. If you are familiar with Russian, you can find nice deployment guide [here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/215653/).

The main advantage of this solution is new DNS zone available inside Docker environment. Containers can call each other by name. But since the reverse lookup is lacking in `SkyDNS`, you'll need to pass hostnames explicitly:

```
 web:
  image: django
  hostname: web.django.dev.skydns.local
  build: ./webapp
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  environment:
    - DEBUG=true
    - SEND_EMAILS=false
```

In this fashion your container will be available by name `web.django.dev.skydns.local` from inside any container.

Comment: Is it true that `SkyDNS` does not require `etcd`? The very first lines of [`Setup/Install` section at their homepage](https://github.com/skynetservices/skydns#setup--install) explicitly mention configuration for use of `etcd`. Also, I quickly skimmed through the article you've mentioned and the solution provided there requires running 2 different containers alongside with my existing configuration. Anyway, thanks for mentioning these services, I'll probably look further into this direction of `service auto-discovery`

Comment: @AndrewDruchenko what you pointed out is ```SkyDNS2```. But I suggest you to try the elder version ```SkyDNS``` first (actually it was described in article). It doesn't require `etcd`.